# Durandal: intercept view loading to handle unauthorized requests (ASP.NET MVC server)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, authorization, durandal

I've just started converting a Knockout-driven SPA to use Durandal. Due to server legacy, views are served through ASP.Net MVC endpoints that return an ActionResult. In the case of accessing a route that should not be available to the current user, or for example when the session has expired, the server will return JSON instead of HTML.

Durandal seems to make the assumption that HTML will always be returned from the specified view endpoint. Is there any way for me to hook into the process of loading a view so I can process the JSON that comes with an unauthorized request?

In the future the server will be updated to use the Web API. At that point, I will have to solve the same problem, but in that case I will have to handle different response codes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you may do,
Instead of letting the default view locator load the view for you, you can add a callback method `getView` method in your viewModel. In the callback method you can load the view (using text.js or jquery), then you have full control of what you want to do with the non-HTML responses (may be switch to a canned error view etc).

More info at Durandal Docs http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM/